# Go copy bytes into struct fields with reflection

Tags: go, reflection

How can I iterate over a byte slice and assign them to the fields of a struct?

```golang
type s struct {
  f1 []byte
  f2 []byte
  f3 []byte
}

func S s {
  x := s{}
  x.f1 = make([]byte, 4)
  x.f1 = make([]byte, 2)
  x.f1 = make([]byte, 2)
  return x
}

func main() {
  data := []byte{83, 117, 110, 83, 0, 1, 0, 65}

  Z := S()
  //pesudo code from here
  i:= 0
  for field in Z {
    field = data[i:len(field)]
    i += len(field)
  }
```

Expecting:

- f1 = [83,117,110,83]
- f2 = [0,1]
- f3 = [0,65]

I've done this in C/C++ before but I can't figure out how to do it in Go. I need the assigning function to be generic as I'm going to have several different structs some of which may not exist in the stream.

Ideally I want to pass in the initialized struct and my code would iterate over the struct fields filling them in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leverage the reflection code in the binary/encoding package.

Step 1: Declare the fields as arrays instead of slices.

```
type S struct {
  F1 [4]byte
  F2 [2]byte
  F3 [2]byte
}
```

Step 2: Decode the data to the struct using [binary.Read](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/binary#Read)

```
var s S
data := []byte{83, 117, 110, 83, 0, 1, 0, 65}
err := binary.Read(bytes.NewReader(data), binary.LittleEndian, &s)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

Step 3: Done!

```
fmt.Print(s) // prints {[83 117 110 83] [0 1] [0 65]}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/H-e8Lusw0RC

Comment: Is there a way to specify that my [4]byte is actually a string in the struct but still only parse 4 bytes ?



Leverage the reflection code in the binary/encoding package.

Step 1: Declare the fields as arrays instead of slices.

```
type S struct {
  F1 string(4) // assuming same size as bytes uint8 or string(2) in uint16 bytes
}```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`reflect.Copy`](https://pkg.go.dev/reflect#Copy). Like the built-in `copy`, it copies data into the destination up to its length. Make sure the fields you need to set are exported.

```
func main() {
    data := []byte{83, 117, 110, 83, 0, 1, 0, 65}

    z := S{
        F1: make([]byte, 4),
        F2: make([]byte, 2),
        F3: make([]byte, 2),
    }
    SetBytes(&z, data)
    fmt.Println(z) // {[83 117 110 83] [0 1] [0 65]}
}

func SetBytes(dst any, data []byte) {
    v := reflect.ValueOf(dst)
    if v.Kind() != reflect.Ptr {
        panic("dst must be addressable")
    }
    v = v.Elem()

    j := 0
    for i := 0; i < v.NumField(); i++ {
        field := v.Field(i)
        if field.Kind() != reflect.Slice {
            continue
        }
        j += reflect.Copy(v.Field(i), reflect.ValueOf(data[j:]))
    }
}
```

Since `data` is assumed to be always `[]byte`, you can subslice it directly.

Alternatively, you can use [`reflect.Value#Slice`](https://pkg.go.dev/reflect#Value.Slice):

```
d := reflect.ValueOf(data)
// and later
j += reflect.Copy(v.Field(i), d.Slice(j, d.Len()))
```

Playground: https://go.dev/play/p/o1MR1qrW5pL